# MPPT and control charge(battery)

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a MPPT controller for my 16V, 0.6A PV panel.

My problem: How best to use the MPPT to charge my 12V 7Ah battery?
Will I need to use a seperate charge controller?

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: We need more information to help with your question: What (specific) MPPT do you have? It is likely that your MPPT can be xonfigured as a charge controller for your battery, but we can't be sure without seeing its specs/documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A normal MPPT will try to deliver as much power to its load as possible.

This is not usually what you want when charging a battery. If you connect it directly to the battery, it may deliver excess current in the first stage of the charge. It will almost certainly deliver too much voltage at the end stage and overcharge the battery.

If you have written your own MPPT (is that what 'realized' means?) then it will be straightforward for you to read up on your battery charging requirements, and modify your algorithm to suit.

If you cannot change the MPPT algorithm, then you will need to cascade an additional battery charge controller.

Be aware that the charge controller will take less power as the charge progresses. The MPPT you have may require a certain minimum load to function, which the charge controller will not provide towards end of charge. How will your MPPT function into a lower load?

If the MPPT you have cannot work into a low load, you will need to add an additional shunt load, filament lamps are a good choice, to the output of the MPPT, when the charger is not taking sufficient power.

Comment: You can give a algoritm ,??

Comment: Do you mean a) can I supply you the algorithm that you need to put into your MPPT to charge a battery or b) confirmation that you can put an algorithm into an MPPT? If (b), then don't forget I said 'If you have written your own MPPT ...', in other words, it's a programmable system. If it's purchased, then chances are that it's a closed system and you won't be able to do much with it, except possibly program the maximum output power, voltage and current, which might get you very close to where you need to be.